# Is there a microsoft based asp.net split container?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, splitcontainer

MSDN has the functionality I'm looking for [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173188%28VS.80%29.aspx). Since microsoft recognizes the usefulness of a split container for the web, is this page using a publically available microsoft created, .net based split container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Javascript js file in the page that references all of the containers.  Alas, that script doesn't appear to be publicly available.

However, this should do the trick:

**jQuery Splitter Plugin**
http://methvin.com/splitter/

An online demo is here:
http://methvin.com/splitter/vsplitter.html